# How to replace an element in AngularJS directive linking function?

Tags: jquery, dom, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a `<row>` AngularJS directive that needs to replace itself (the `<row>` tag must not be present in the DOM after execution) with a dynamic template that can contain any HTML code.

The problem in using `replace: true` is that it does not work with table's `<tr>` tags and that the template is dynamically chosen.

So I'm trying to find a way to replace the element in the linking function, with no success.

Using jQuery's `.replaceWith()` breaks `ngRepeat` for unknown reason.

Any hints?

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fMP9s/)

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle of what you've tried? Much easier to see then try to discern from your description.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fMP9s/

Comment: I think that this question has no solution, since replacing <row>, which holds ng-repeat OBVIUSLY breaks ng-repeats!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Your fiddle seems pretty basic but you should be able to just use `outerHTML`

```
element[0].outerHTML ='<div>I should not be red</div>';
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/fMP9s/1/)**

If you have to deal with `ng-repeat` you can bind your items to a scope property and reference them in your template that you compile.  Once it is compiled you can use jQuery `replaceWith()`

html

```
<row items="items">***</row>
```

directive

```
.directive('row', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            items: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var html ='<div ng-repeat="item in items">I should not be red</div>';
            var e =$compile(html)(scope);
            element.replaceWith(e);
        }
    };
});
```

[`ng-repeat` example](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/fMP9s/2/)

Answer (score 102):

Mark's answer will work, however, that example is too limited to show the whole picture. Whereas Mark's directive might indeed suffice for common and simple UI components, for more complex operations, that pattern is one to be avoided. Below I explain **in detail** the reason behind this. In fact, Angular **already** provides a far simpler way to replace the directive element with a template. It can be found at the bottom of this answer.

Here is how a directive looks behind the scenes:

```
.directive('row', function ($compile) {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
          items: "="
      },

      // Whether you define it this way or not, this is the order of
      // operation (execution) behind every AngularJS directive.
      // When you use the more simple syntax, Angular actually generates this
      // structure for you (this is done by the $compile service):

      compile: function CompilingFunction($templateElement, $templateAttributes, transcludeFn) {

        // The compile function hooks you up into the DOM before any scope is
        // applied onto the template. It allows you to read attributes from
        // the directive expression (i.e. tag name, attribute, class name or
        // comment) and manipulate the DOM (and only the DOM) as you wish.

        // When you let Angular generate this portion for you, it basically
        // appends your template into the DOM, and then some ("some" includes
        // the transclude operation, but that's out of the $scope of my answer ;) )

          return function LinkingFunction($scope, $element, $attrs) {

            // The link function is usually what we become familiar with when
            // starting to learn how to use directives. It gets fired after
            // the template has been compiled, providing you a space to
            // manipulate the directive's scope as well as DOM elements.

            var html ='<div ng-repeat="item in items">I should not be red</div>';
            var e = $compile(html)($scope);
            $element.replaceWith(e);
          };
      }
  };
});
```

What can we make out of that? It is obvious then, that manually calling `$compile` for the same DOM layout **twice** is redundant, bad for performance **and** bad for your teeth, too. What should you do instead? Simply compile your DOM where it **should** be compiled:

```
.directive('row', function ($compile) {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div ng-repeat="item in items">I should not be red</div>',
      scope: {
          items: "="
      },

      compile: function CompilingFunction($templateElement, $templateAttributes) {
          $templateElement.replaceWith(this.template);

          return function LinkingFunction($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            // play with the $scope here, if you need too.
          };
      }
  };
});
```

---

If you want to dive in further under the hood of directives, here is what I like to call the Unofficial [AngularJS Directive Reference](http://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-directive/)

Once you're done with that head over here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives

---

## Now, as promised, here is the solution you came here for:

Using `replace: true`:

```
.directive('row', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-repeat="item in items">I should not be red</div>',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            items: "="
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Why don't they put this in the Angular page for directives? replace: true was the first thing I wanted to do when I reached for a directive. Excellent post.

Comment: Thanks. Even at version 1.3 the Angular documentation is still sub-par  and leaves a lot to be desired. Also the choice of Google Groups (without syntax highlighting nor even a `<pre>` tag) is hard to understand. Lucky we have SO :)

Comment: `replace: true` is deprecated and will be removed in Angular 1.2.0: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-templateurl-

Comment: That's true, and for those wondering why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194972/why-is-replace-deprecated-in-angularjs

Comment: `Replace` won't be removed until the next major version...along with everything else.

Comment: @pilau so now I know why my teeth ache xD ... Great answer btw!

Comment: With `replace: true` [being deprecated](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/eec6394a342fb92fba5270eee11c83f1d895e9fb), [@Mark Coleman's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17091823/114558) is now the appropriate solution, correct?

Comment: @rinogo this was already asked in 2014 (look up the comments). De-facto, we are using Angular 1.5.8 and `replace: true` still works (I just checked). It received deprecated status in 1.2.0 but they never went through with it.

Comment: This won't work if you need something from the parent scope to determine the template for the directive